# CTE in DB2 subquery

Tags: recursion, db2, common-table-expression, db2-luw

I'm trying to use a recursive CTE in the from clause in DB2 luw 11.1. This CTE works by itself:

```
with i (i) as ( 
    values (1)
    union all 
    select i + 1 from i
    where i < 3 
) 
select * from i;

            I
-------------
            1
            2
            3
```

But when I try it in the `from` clause:

```
select * 
from (
    with i (i) as ( 
        values (1)
        union all 
        select i + 1 from i
        where i < 3 
    )
    select * from i
) i;
ERRO próximo da linha 1:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "as" was found following "*
from (
with i (i)".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN".
```

A similar construct works in Postgresql. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need a CTE in the `FROM` clause? Looks like an X-Y problem to me. As you can see, it's syntactically incorrect in DB2 (and semantically unnecessary).

Comment: @mustaccio It could also be a correlated subquery in the select list but I thought it would be cleaner in a lateral join. I can not test the correlated subquery now. Is it legal?

Answer (score 2):

Hi "with" statement must be first in db2 query ,try this

```
with i (i) as (
    values (1)
    union all
    select i + 1 from i
    where i < 3
)
select *
   from (

           select * from i
         ) i;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, your query works just fine in DB2 v11.5.4.0:

```sql
select * 
from (
    with i (i) as ( 
        values (1)
        union all 
        select i + 1 from i
        where i < 3 
    )
    select * from i
) i;
```

producing the expected:

```
|I  |
|---|
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
```

But it didn't work yet in version DB2 v11.1.4.4 as can be seen in this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b1833c47a9c561c11eba7b4934f646e0)

Comment: Thank you for the update. I still don't have access to 11.5 to test it.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: The current version on docker hub is 11.5: https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2