# Cannot use a CTE in a scalar subquery in Db2

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use a CTE in a DB2 LUW v11.5.4.0 scalar subquery, but this doesn't work:

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM SYSIBM.dual
WHERE 1 IN (
  WITH t (x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.dual)
  SELECT * FROM t
);
```

I'm getting this error:

> SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "AS" was found following "1 IN (
> WITH t (x)".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14

Can this be done? Is there a workaround?

(This is similar but not the same as this question, [which is about derived tables, not scalar subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44336291/521799). Derived tables support CTE in version 11.5.4.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in version 11.5.4.0, it's possible to use CTEs in derived tables, so the query can be emulated as follows:

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM SYSIBM.dual
WHERE 1 IN (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    WITH t (x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.dual)
    SELECT * FROM t
  ) t
);
```

However, this workaround also doesn't work in older versions of Db2, e.g. in [version v11.1.4.4 as can be seen in this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=aec1c71323bf96260790803a693ed302) or [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44336291/521799). The workaround in those versions will be to push the CTE to the top level of the query:

```sql
WITH t (x) AS (SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.dual)
SELECT 1
FROM SYSIBM.dual
WHERE 1 IN (
  SELECT * FROM t
);
```

#### Side note

HSQLDB seems to suffer from a similar limitation / bug, see https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1617.